# How can I change the body size during report generation?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

So I have 1 report, and I need two different version of it when I export to Excel and export to PDF.

I already know how to hide certain report items depending on it being PDF or Excel, but the other problem I'm having is that the table I'm hiding is very wide.

It's for the excel version of the report, which is fine. However, the PDF version of the report now has blank pages because the body of the report is bigger than portrait page size.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you using rectangles to place the items in and then using dynamic visibility of those rectangles? How are you making the visibility dependent on whether they use chooses xl or pdf? (or am I misreading your question)

Comment: I'm using the visibility of the Tablix itself using this: =IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCEL",false,true)

Comment: nice one - I never knew about this possibility. I mentioned rectangles as I use them in some reports:  add the rectabgle and then drag the tablix into the rectangle. Then maybe try hiding the rectangle (all it's contents will also vanish) ...just an experiment to see if it helps solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an exhaustive search, i've basically come to the conclusion that "no, you can't"